# Can hanging a 70 lbs punching bag from my garage ceiling cause damage?

Tags: ceiling, garage, attic, structural, beam

Took a look in the attic above the garage to find somewhere to hang my 70 lbs punching bag. After seeing what was up there, I wasn't sure it was a good idea anymore so I was hoping to get some feedback.

Garage depth: 24 ft / width: 30 ft

Here is a link to more pictures of the attic so you can have a better idea of the structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhREe.jpg

The red arrow shows the spot I was going to hang the bag from. It's a 2x12 going all the way from the front to the back of the garage, supported by those respective walls. Is that considered a beam?

I hope this is enough information to determine if it can hold and not cause structural issues.

[image: The red arrow is the spot I was going to hang the bag from]

[image: The other side]

Thanks!

Comment: note: drill down between the boards where the red arrow points .... then lay a piece of a 2x4 on top of that ... drill a hole in the piece of 2x4 and run the hanging bolt all the way through and put a washer and nut on top

Comment: @jsotola sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this

drill from the attic side

afterthought: use lockwashers

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had to buy a threaded rod and a coupling nut because I couldn't find a eye bolt long enough but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a typical garage attic, but 70 lbs isn't too much of a concern unless those toolboxes are loaded up and weigh another 70, and another, and another....

Just make sure you anchor to a robust framing member, and not just one thin board that could tear loose or fail over time. The 2x12 should be fine.

Comment: It's 70 pounds when the bag is just hanging there. When it's being used, the attachment point will be getting jerked around with quite a bit more force, I imagine.

Comment: And yeah, that is a really weird looking attic structure.